# M2.1.8 Category text appearing in 2nd column

Tags: magento-2.1, design

I am creating pages with text from Categories and have selected "2 columns with right bar" in the Design tab. However the text in the category is showing in the second column - see screenshot. I intend to add some more widgets in the right hand column so this is not the appearance I want. How do I make the text stop at the beginning of the 2nd column? I do not want to hack the core.

[image]

Comment: You can remove compare and wishlist block using xml

Comment: I need to keep those and other widgets I will add will have the same problem.

Comment: your "category-view" block coming out of " column main " place it inside " column main" and will solve your problem

Comment: How do I do that?